# Proper way to sync a table from another similar table with a few different columns while inserts and updates are happening

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, alter-table

We need to alter an existing InnoDb table with 10+ million records to add a few columns. We tried simple alter table query and it took almost an hour to complete. However, the change did not reflect. No error details available.

So, we are trying this approach:

- creating a new table with same schema,
- then altering the table
- then syncing up data from the existing table
- then just renaming the first table to use a different name (application will cause error during this time) and then renaming the 2nd table to the production name, being used by application.

**Problem in hand**

I am not sure how to go ahead with the syncing, while application is live. 
 I think we should go ahead with syncing, instead of just dumping and restoring. If dumping is to be done, should be done by shutting down traffic.
Edits can happen to the table in question corresponding to txns done. So, we need to ensure that in addition to sanity checks on total accounts migrated, we also don’t lose any edits done to the table during migration.

Is a stored procedure needed in this scenario?

**Update**

We need to make sure no updates to existing table (being written from application) and inserts are missed. Not sure if stored procedure is the solution here.
Do we need to shut down writes completely for this? Any way of doing this by keeping application running?

Comment: Try removing all the indexes from the table then alter and add index again. You can test in your dev environment if it works then do the same in production.

Comment: See here the meaning of [crore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore). It basically means: ten million.

Comment: [MySQL 8.0: InnoDB now supports Instant ADD COLUMN](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-innodb-now-supports-instant-add-column)